# NetBeans Cannot Find JTextField.append()

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans

I have NetBeans 8.2 on my desktop (Windows 10) and my laptop (debian), I can use the append method on my desktop but not my laptop.  When I try to use it I get cannot find symbol.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NetBeans Cannot Find JTextField.append()
>   I can use the append method on my desktop but not my laptop.

I doubt that you can use the `JTextField#append(...)` method *anywhere*

Please check the [JTextField entry in the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) in this situation, and you will see that the problem is that JTextField *does not have an append method*. This method is found for JTextArea (please check the [JTextArea API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to see for yourself) but not JTextField. If you need to append text, then you will need to do it yourself:

```
String myText = myTextField.getText() + "new text";
myTextField.setText(myText);
```

Comment: I see, I just assumed there wouldn't be a difference.

Comment: @will: That's where an IDE like the NetBeans IDE really shines -- it will warn you directly and immediately if your assumptions are off, and again, in that situation, always go to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) first.